# Where should I put take the string of last two chars

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi I need to narrow down the search string to allow users to put some flags at the end of search like "/A" or "/W". This is wpf and MVVM. I tried to put it in the property but it looks like it doesn't work. Where should I put it if I can't put it in the property.

```
    public NavDataType Type
    {

        get
        {
            return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_type.ToString().Substring(_type.ToString().Length - 2, 2) == "/A")
                _type = NavDataType.Airport;
            if (_type.ToString().Substring(_type.ToString().Length - 2, 2) == "/W")
                _type = NavDataType.Waypoint;
            if (_type.ToString().Substring(_type.ToString().Length - 2, 2) == "/N")
                _type = NavDataType.Navaid;
            SetProperty(ref _type, value, "Type");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note. I would take the logic in your if statement:

_type.ToString().Substring(_type.ToString().Length - 2, 2)

save the result in a variable so you don't have to do that calculation over and over.

Comment: you should use string.EndsWith like `if (_type.ToString().EndsWith("/A"))`

Comment: Can the user have multiple flags? i.e. `"Something /A /W"`?

Comment: No, can't have multiple flags. What is wrong with the logic of the if statement?

Comment: Why not a combobox next to your search box for an optional parameter? Now your user can't fat finger it and you don't deal with the pain of string parsing all possibilities.

Comment: This code does not make sense; why are you calling `_type.ToString()`? What is `_type`? An `enum`? Converting that to a string will return a static value, not anything the user put in a search. You never declare `_type` and `/` is not a valid character for an `enum`, so I don't see how that code could ever work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (_type.ToString().Substring(_type.ToString().Length - 2, 2) == "/N")
            _type = NavDataType.Navaid;
        SetProperty(ref _type, value, "Type");
```

the problem is that you're setting `_type` in the if statements (works correcty), but then the `SetProperty` call is *overwriting* that  with whatever `value` was when it got passed in.